# Excess white space between columns in beamer slide

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, spacing, columns

I'd like to remove the excess space between two columns on a Beamer slide. There's a graph in one column, and a table in the other. I'd like the graph and the table to be closer together on the slide. Thank you ahead.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}   % wide frame
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Corpus size}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar,
    bar width=.1\textwidth,
    height=.55\textwidth, % Adjust the height of the axis to fit within the frame
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits=.5,  % this controls the blank space to the left and to the right, but needs these two lines below:
%    xmin={Texts}, % 
    xmax={Words}, % 
    ymax=1500, % this is where the y axis stops and the wavy line is drawn
    xtick=data,
    symbolic x coords={Texts,Words},
    restrict y to domain*=0:1700, % Cut values off here, has to be higher than ymax
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
        \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=2pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1) -- (rel axis cs:2,1);
    },
    nodes near coords={%
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
    },
    axis lines*=left,  % this is where the wavy line is drawn, but it is hidden
    clip=false
]
\addplot [fill=orange!50] coordinates {(Texts,1117) (Words,5601719)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
%
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{ccc} \hline
Subcorpus & Texts & Words \\ \hline \hline
Pseudo & 117 &  1000000  \\ 
Science & 1000 & 4000000 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white space between your image and table is a combination of two different effects:

- by default, beamer changes the page margins for columns to create some space between them. This is easy to avoid: you'll just need to use the `onlytextwidth` option
- the second factor is that your image and your table is much smaller than the width of your columns. You also centre them, which creates space between them. To avoid this you could a) make the left column smaller and the right column bigger and b) remove the centering so that your image and table will be left aligned inside their columns.

---

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}   % wide frame
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Corpus size}
\begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar,
    bar width=0.7cm,
    height=.45\textheight, % Adjust the height of the axis to fit within the frame
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits=.5,  % this controls the blank space to the left and to the right, but needs these two lines below:
%    xmin={Texts}, % 
    xmax={Words}, % 
    ymax=1500, % this is where the y axis stops and the wavy line is drawn
    xtick=data,
    symbolic x coords={Texts,Words},
    restrict y to domain*=0:1700, % Cut values off here, has to be higher than ymax
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
        \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=2pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1) -- (rel axis cs:2,1);
    },
    nodes near coords={%
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
    },
    axis lines*=left,  % this is where the wavy line is drawn, but it is hidden
    clip=false
]
\addplot [fill=orange!50] coordinates {(Texts,1117) (Words,5601719)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
%
\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
\small
\begin{tabular}{ccc} \hline
Subcorpus & Texts & Words \\ \hline \hline
Pseudo & 117 &  1000000  \\ 
Science & 1000 & 4000000 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this solution, it works really well

Comment: @Tony You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line:

```
    \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=2pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1) -- (rel axis cs:2,1);
```

which caused the wavy line to extend further to the right than needed, and because the line was drawn in white, its length was not visible.

these coordinates fixed the problem:

```
    \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=2pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1) -- (rel axis cs:1,1);
```

Fixed slide:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}   % wide frame
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Corpus size}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar,
    bar width=.1\textwidth,
    height=.55\textwidth, % Adjust the height of the axis to fit within the frame
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits=.5,  % this controls the blank space to the left and to the right, but needs these two lines below:
%    xmin={Texts}, % 
    xmax={Words}, % 
    ymax=1500, % this is where the y axis stops and the wavy line is drawn
    xtick=data,
    symbolic x coords={Texts,Words},
    restrict y to domain*=0:1700, % Cut values off here, has to be higher than ymax
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
        \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=2pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1) -- (rel axis cs:1,1);
    },
    nodes near coords={%
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
    },
    axis lines*=left,  % this is where the wavy line is drawn, but it is hidden
    clip=false
]
\addplot [fill=orange!50] coordinates {(Texts,1117) (Words,5601719)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
%
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{ccc} \hline
Subcorpus & Texts & Words \\ \hline \hline
Pseudo & 117 &  1000000  \\ 
Science & 1000 & 4000000 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```